# Travian changing village name gives 'Invalid Token' with webrequests

Tags: c#, ajax, json

### Travian changing village name gives 'Invalid Token' with webrequests

I'm trying to change the village name by using webrequests. The original webrequest is:

http://ts9.travian.com/ajax.php?cmd=changeVillageName

```
POST /ajax.php?cmd=changeVillageName HTTP/1.1
Host: ts9.travian.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-Request: JSON
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Referer: http://ts9.travian.com/dorf1.php
Content-Length: 99
Cookie: sess_id=d6785b074b551c8f2bcdc31b7a314f9a; lowRes=0; T3E=jICvjEyjMlS3JAfAnZu%2FEA%3D%3D%3A6RoqZtSC3svl61Vi9hEBmO7xA0%2FJdL6xESd3tTKjvKM2UqoAiTf93aHbstIjJ0a7Yvf4c7vtp05Z4Kqm8Sg8OsJjM6waVRalUUKZWnU0fKHLqbvUcksUYSz2TKqMjhIgx8c6A9KRKyIvfdPOX7FffQ%3D%3D%3AP9Wn2BVlp9KeMlaOfyuG3ulblfv4%2BGhsswiIWeG5BNA%3D;travian_toggle=hero%3Aexpanded%2Cinfobox%3Aexpanded%2Cvillagelist%3Acollapsed; highlightsToggle=true
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
cmd=changeVillageName&name=SWAAGGERs%20village&did=39020&ajaxToken=6697441f78fefc90ca84c0e3891661cb
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 10:31:54 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8;
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

The response is:

```
{
    ajaxToken: null,
    response: {"error":true,"errorMsg":"Token invalid","data":{"html":""}}
}
```

The way im posting my request:

```
POST @ http://ts9.travian.com/ajax.php?cmd=changeVillageName
Data @ cmd=changeVillageName&name=ogdgpvqxf479&did=39020&ajaxToken=da56a3af2fc3cb6b629a091533d09e4e
REF  @ http://ts9.travian.com/dorf1.php
```

Is there something im missing out? (If I need to post more data like cookies, I can do that if needed)

The ajaxToken is stored in window.ajaxToken in javascript, but is send with every request. The ajaxtoken is set in every page at the top by

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.ajaxToken = '4bf2392b506df3ebb1f4873a66f766d6';
    </script>
```

EDIT:
I've spoofed my cookies used by these webrequests in my browser and ive been able to do it that way... Still didn't figure out what causes it.

Answer (score 0):

The login session is kept via cookies. So, without cookies the server can't tell which account to associate the HTTP request with and whether that user is authenticated to change the given village's name. If the web server didn't do this, you'd be able to change the name of any village on the server.
The window.ajaxToken JavaScript variable (which isn't anything standard, just something this particular website does) is used to prevent [cross site request forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). It is also known as a CSRF token.
The web server serves the page with the CSRF token, but also stores that CSRF token on the server and associates it with the current login session. Whenever the server receives an AJAX request, it identifies the login session using cookies and validates that the request came from a page that it served by checking the CSRF token.

If they didn't do this, it would be possible for other websites to change your village names without you knowing. 
Let's say I want to get you banned by naming your villages "I use bots and macros." On my website, getbannedfromtravian.com, I have JavaScript like this:

```
    $.post({
        url: "http://ts9.travian.com/ajax.php?cmd=changeVillageName",
            data: {
            cmd=changeVillageName,
            did=12345,
            name="I use bots and macros" 
        }
    });
```

When you visit my website, this JavaScript will run. Your browser will be kind enough to supply the cookies it associates with ts9.travian.com, including your login session, with the request. 
However, because I did not supply the CSRF token that the server associates with the login session and serves in every page, it knows that this request did not come from a page it served and that it should be ignored, leaving your village's name unaltered.